# Asp.Net Mvc, Rdlc reports - How do I show associated name from parent table instead of just it's ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, rdlc

I am using **Asp.net MVC 5** with **EF 6** for a college project. I am using **RDLC** for generating reports.

I created a simple report showing Items and its associated details. But I have no idea how to show Manufacturer Name of an Item instead of its ManufacturerID.

Could anyone help me out with this?

It has been so many days, and I am still struggling with reports. Looks like, its easy with webforms and ADO.net. But I am finding it hard to incorporate reports in MVC using Entity Framework.

**If there are better options please let me know.**

Well for this report I refered to **[this tutorial](http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2013/09/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4.html) .**

Here is my code for generating reports:

```
public ActionResult Report(string id)
    {
        LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "Report_item.rdlc");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            lr.ReportPath = path;
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        List<Item> cm = new List<Item>();            
        cm = db.Items.ToList();

        ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("MyData_Item", cm);
        lr.DataSources.Add(rd);
        string reportType = id;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        string deviceInfo =
        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>" + id + "</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = lr.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);


        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
    }
```

Item Model :

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Item")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Generic Name")]
    public int? DrugGenericNameID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Manufacturer")]
    public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Categeory")]
    public Categeory? Categeory { get; set; }   

    public int AlertQty { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Update")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }


    //reference entity
    public virtual DrugGenericName DrugGenericName { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseItem> PurchaseItems { get; set; }

}
public enum Categeory
{
    Drug,
    Supplies,
    other
}
```

Here is my report. How can I derive associated Names instead of its ID?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a representation of your datasource with the tables/fields?

Comment: I added model and report image for more clarity. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Generally RDLC reports use a fairly flat structure for their data model - you can have associated child tables within the report; but for a flat table in your report all of your fields should be in the same table/model.

So, consider this as your Item model (removed most of your original properties for brevity):

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Item")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Properties as per your original model ...


    //reference entity
    public virtual DrugGenericName DrugGenericName { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseItem> PurchaseItems { get; set; }

    // Added properties:
    public string ManufacturerName {
       get { return Manufacturer.Name; }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

You'll then be able to reference the Manufacturer Name directly.

Comment: But with this, I have to update database  and this process would create redundancy. Isn't it?

Comment: In that case just do the same but with a DTO object which represents the report layout and map your properties onto it (you can use Automapper to cut down the amount of work)

Comment: No need to update the database - you should be able to create "readonly" columns in your model that are ignored by the database (you may have to decorate them with attributes appropriate to your entity framework).  Otherwise, just do what Charleh suggests and create a DTO object, then use Automapper to map the two.